# Getting Error Receiver 'GMSCoordinateBounds' for class message is a forward declaration while building react native ios code on xcode

Tags: ios, react-native-ios

while building react native code using xcode for ios getting this error and not able to run application tried to clear node modules package-lock.json file, pod removal and all the basic steps but after each and every try still getting or to say build fails at this step

Comment: did you find any solution?